# How to test a newsstand new issue?

Tags: ios, cocoa, newsstand-kit

And I have a newsstand app in appstore, and Now I want to add the function of adding new issue with Newsstand, and then my newsstand icon will be changed to a new screenshot with [new] ribben , but I didn't find some test Environment of Newsstand adding new issue, someone can give me some advice , thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately as far as I know there is no test environment to test the Newsstand icon being updated across the app store. I mean you cannot test without actually submitting you app to the app-store.

If your app is Newsstand enabled in the iTunes Connect, Then go to Newsstand section in your app detail page. There you will find the "issues" section where you can add the details for your latest issue like Cover Art, Published Date etc.,

And your updates are reflected in about 24hrs across the app-store.